# Should iframes be used for web programming if I plan to convert the site to an android/iOS app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

I'm trying to decide if I should use iframes on my website that I plan to turn into an android/iOS app. Is this a bad idea? If so, what other features would be better to compartmentalize the site.

Comment: what issues are you trying to solve with iframes?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "turn into an android/iOS app". Are you talking about re-doing it completely native or using something like PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using [Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) on your site from the start. 
Jquery mobile does a lot of work with loading content into DIVs with Ajax, rather than using iframes.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main problems with an iframe has to do with bookmarks and navigation. If you are using it to simply embed a page inside your content then umm its okay but i would prefer to do it differently.

So iframe = bad SEO, now if you can do it without an iframe, that is a better option.

Maybe if you want something for Mobiles as well you should look into HTML5 with responsive design, Usability and SEO friendly website (iframes are not SEO friendly).

It's 'bad practice' to use them without understanding the iframe drawbacks.

Responsive design is really an advanced way to make your website clear for all browsers, now despite what libraries you use (Jquery or AngularJS) and whatever languages in the backend (PHP, ASP.NET or Java) you can achieve the responsive design easily.

==About the app==
Now about the andriod/IOS app, Keep in mind the app is built standalone, and it wont open in the browser you have to think of webservices like Rest, so your website can communicate with any platform.

hope this was helpful enough.